# How to find out my Galaxy Nexus' version? (maguro, toro or toroplus)

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-nexus, installation

I have a Galaxy Nexus phone.

I want to install JellyBean manually, but I don't know which one of [these](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#takjujop40d) I should download. How do I know if my phone is maguro, toro or toroplus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `Settings > About phone > Model number`,
and see which one matches:

- Samsung Galaxy Nexus (Maguro; GSM/HSPA+) - GT-I9250
- Samsung Galaxy Nexus (Toro; Verizon; CDMA/LTE) - SGH-I515
- Samsung Galaxy Nexus (Toro Plus; Sprint; CDMA/LTE) - SPH-L700

**Edit #1:** You can also check the back casing if it has Verizon (toro) or Sprint (toroplus) written on it. If not, then you have maguro.

Comment: Model number is just "Galaxy Nexus"

Comment: @shift66 What is the Build number in the `About phone`?

Comment: JOP40D I Know that it's jelly bean 4.2.1 actually I've installed the 4.1.1 about 3 months ago (don't remember which of the variants). and then Android updated to 4.2.1. but in last week something happened and now there are some bugs. I just want install fresh OS.

Comment: Do you have the phone right now? Does it have a writing at the back? Sprint? Verizon?

Comment: No, just google and samsung. It means that my phone is maguro?

Comment: @shift66 Then, it's safe to say you have: Samsung Galaxy Nexus (Maguro; GSM/HSPA+) - GT-I9250

Comment: Just note-- this is true as long as you know that the back cover is the original! (since one can easily buy an OEM back w/ only Google And Samsung logos on it).

Comment: I have an old Galaxy Nexus from Sprint, but the bootloader screen said I had toro, not toroplus. Also, the toroplus Cyanogenmod refused to install because it insisted I had toro.