# 4.3 OTA Update Install Fail With Motochopper Root 4.2.2 Google Nexus 7

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-7, root-access, 4.3-jelly-bean, ota-update

I am using Stock Android 4.2.2 on Nexus 7 2012 Tablet. I rooted my tablet using the [Motochopper Root](http://hexamob.com/how-to-root/motochopper-method/). I was able to download OTA 4.3 Update using normal procedure on my tablet however, when I tried installing the update, it just stuck at the android guy with error at startup. I tried downloading the OTA update again as it just disappeared, however it is stuck at waiting to download. I tried [Nexus Tool Kit](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/) downloaded Stock 4.3 OTA and tried to install it using ADB sideload command. However it gave an error and mentioned some error file and exited. Please Help me out . I also tried full unroot with SuperSu but it also did not work.

Answer (score 1):

[Download stock ROM from Google](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images), and flash it.
To check correct version for your Nexus 7 2012, [see this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38649/how-to-find-out-my-galaxy-nexus-version-maguro-toro-or-toroplus/38650#38650).

Since it would now be stock, you'd have to root it again.

Comment: I dont want to lose any data.

Comment: How do I achieve that??

Comment: @aibk01 If you can still connect your tablet to a PC and access the files in it, copy them. Otherwise, too late. It is recommended to always backup before doing something that might break your phone, like rooting or flashing a different ROM. I'm afraid you'll have to do a factory reset (in recovery mode) before flashing a new ROM.